# Social Commenting WebPartPropertyDisplayItems property

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to change the Social comment webpart -WebPartPropertyDisplayItems property to display more than 10 items in the comments section.

But its still takes only 10.is ter anyother way to update this value.

Thanks,

Sudan

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself but you can Go to Web Parts under Site Settings:

Download the Social Comment WebPart file (.webpart) and open it with any XML Editor. Change the WebPartPropertyDisplayItems to the number you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      ....
      <properties>
          <property name="WebPartPropertyDisplayItems" type="int">15</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
```

Save the .webpart again and upload it again to the WebPart gallery, and see the results.

Unfortunately, `SocialCommentWebPart` class is sealed and therefore can't be inherited.

Comment: I have tried updating it.but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that this property only controls how many items are displayed with a max of 10 items.  If there are more items than the property value, or if there are more than 10 items, paging will be enabled.

**Update:**
If you want to display more than 10 comments you will need to create a custom web part that reads the social comments and displays the content in the format you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But is there any way we could override this 10 limit.

Comment: As Mike suggested, try adding 10 or more comments and see if paging get enabled on Web part?

Comment: Yes, the paging gets enabled, But i wanted to disable the paging and display all the comments in the same page.